# REST architecture - handle data processing in model or controller?

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, architecture

I have an MVC web-app with a REST endpoint that receives JSON formatted data which needs to be parsed, validated and persisted to the database. The REST endpoint is mapped to a controller function.

What I need to know is where the parsing, validation and persistence should take place. Should it be done in the controller function that is mapped to the REST endpoint or should I be using the controller to simply route the data to the model layer for processing? What is the recommended way of handling this scenario?

Comment: clarify your REST endpoint, does it expects `String` to hold incoming JSON data or a complex object ? Generally in Jersey+Jackson Rest implementation incoming JSON data gets converted to complex object which you receive as argument and further processing deal with this object..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you want your model to operate on the level that is independent of the representation. Therefore, you typically want your parsing done in the view or in the controller; the tasks associated with validation, computation, and persistence should be done in the model.

The data for these operations should be supplied in a way that is independent of representation. For example, if your RESTful service consumes XML input, the view or the controller should deal with the parsing. The model should see object representations of the parsed input. This would let you switch representation simply by providing a different view - for example, you would be able to change your service to process JSON input without touching your model.

Note that this is part of MVC division of responsibilities that holds true outside of RESTful architectures.